# E-commerce solution

Tags: e-commerce

I am working on a small academic project where I need to create a web application that allows user:

1. register
2. upload a product with all its details such as price, description, photos
3. search for product
4. contact product owners

Can this be done using wordpress and some plugins? is there any other alternatives?

Comment: Pretty much anything *can* be done using WordPress. And for everything that can be done with it, there's always alternatives out there. That being said, this is a well packaged [shopping question](http://meta.wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1217/update-our-faq-and-abandon-theme-plugin-recommendations), if you'd ask me.

Comment: yes you can do this by wordpress and for ecommerce use plugin wp-ecommerce